# jQuery .off('click') Prevent Jumping to Top

Tags: jquery, onclick, preventdefault

I have a check box that enables/disables a panel in my accordion. It currently works in the sense that it will expand the accordion when the checkbox is checked, and it will not expand when the checkbox is not checked.

There is a problem that occurs though when I call

```
$('#accordionSection').off('click');
```

When I click the panel it sends me to the top of the page, which I do not want, I want to stay where I am in the page.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
if ($('#myCheckbox').is(':checked')) {
                $('#accordionSection').on('click', AccordionSelectionClickHandler('.accordionContainer > dd', '.accordionContainer > a > dt'));
            } else {
                $('#accordionSection').off('click');
            }
```

Any suggestions without completely switching up this syntax? I have tried `return false` and I can't quite figure out a proper way to implement `preventDefault()` in this case.

Comment: A fiddle or site would be very helpful to see what is happening, as .off() should not move the page at all.

Comment: Can you make a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) showing a more exact example? Is it possible that you are registering the handler multiple times ?

Comment: Can you include the html?  Is the clicked element an anchor tag with an href of #?

Comment: When you remove the click event, the default behavior is no longer being prevented, therefore when it is clicked, the url is changed to `currenturl + "#"` resulting in a jump to top. Maybe you should instead have a flag that disables the click handler without having to unbind the event.

Comment: It is an anchor tag with an href of # @JamesMontagne